# функция не передается в $(window).resize()

Tags: jquery, функции, методы, resize

Подскажите что  я делаю неправильно и в чем моя ошибка...
немогу передать одну и ту же функцию двум методам:

В таком виде работает только при загрузке страницы, а при resize-не работает.

```
$(document).ready(calcHeight());
function calcHeight(){
let bgWidth=$(".wrap").width();
let bgHeight=bgWidth/100*83.4;
 $(".wrap").height(bgHeight);
}

$(window).resize(calcHeight());
```

А вот если написать следующим образом то работает.... но почему и как сделать правильно?

```
$(document).ready(calcHeight());
function calcHeight(){
let bgWidth=$(".wrap").width();
let bgHeight=bgWidth/100*83.4;
 $(".wrap").height(bgHeight);
}

$(window).resize(function(){
let bgWidth=$(".wrap").width();
let bgHeight=bgWidth/100*83.4;
 $(".wrap").height(bgHeight);
});
```

Comment: используйте ссылку на функцию а не её вызов - `$(document).ready(calcHeight);` а не `$(document).ready(calcHeight());`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    calcHeight()
});
```